# Atom shows ModuleNotFoundError when running python script

Tags: python, configuration, virtualenv, atom-editor

I'm running Mac OS X (10.14.4) and I'm attempting to follow YouTube tutorial; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDaxeg4HKQY; Image Detection with YOLO v2 Process Video in Python + openCV

In a UNIX Terminal I'm able to do the following:

1. Configure a virtual environment and activate it;
   `source activate tensorvid`
2. Run a python script to setup the necessary dependencies
   `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`
3. Run a python script successfully
   `python video_processing.py`

Here is the initial code present video_processing.py:

```
import cv2
from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
import numpy as np
import time

option = {

    'model': 'cfg/yolo.cfg',
    'load': 'bin/yolo.weights',
    'threshold': 0.15
}

#tfnet = TFNet(option)

capture = cv2.VideoCapture('CallOnMe.mp4')

colors = [tuple(255 * np.random.rand(3)) for i in range(5)]

for color in colors:
    print(color)
```

Here is the correct output shown in the Terminal:

```
(204.81913044109854, 251.10740779370366, 179.94942134863612)
(252.91320724585321, 180.778985117877, 190.80678674396898)
(192.82964108641886, 186.81635896070537, 9.692333421690345)
(88.90586768830556, 33.25890210180309, 201.9617662283273)
(71.27947539601615, 253.32836287511097, 171.81978416084678)
```

However, when I try the above using ATOM for Mac I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macuser/darkflow-master/video_processing.py", line 1, in <module>
import cv2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

In Atom:

1. I've created a virtual environment using 'Virtualenv' and named it 'tensorvid'
2. I've tried to configure the 'script' using 'configure script' but that doesn't seem to work

Does anyone know how to configure Atom with the UNIX commands given so it works please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have an answer to my own question.

I simply installed the 'Hydrogen' package via Atom --> Preferences --> Packages

Now I can start a virtual environment and control it all within the Atom application.

Problem solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install cv2 before it will work. cv2 is really opencv but to install it you need to activate your virtual environment and then type: `pip install opencv-python`. On a [discussion](https://github.com/jazzsaxmafia/video_to_sequence/issues/3)  dated in July 2018 it was stated that opencv was not compatible with python 3.7 but did work with versions 3.5 and 3.65. It may be compatible now.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. But now I get a series of different error messages. The last error stating... `'File "/Users/macuser/darkflow-master/darkflow/net/yolo/predict.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ...cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes import yolo_box_constructor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes' ` This is despite the fact that I have already run the command `pip install cython` which shows the following `Requirement already satisfied: cython in /Users/miteshparmar/miniconda3/envs/tensorvid/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.29.7)`

Comment: Also I'd thought I'd mention, the above runs perfectly in a terminal giving a series of numbers `(167.24487239904903, 92.36106749638301, 196.97289662535735)
(30.473560441828184, 215.50265897628597, 134.1766434458056)
(28.125851828613687, 45.840692571205516, 48.93318662297744)
(189.94142724689846, 203.98157537371233, 61.15488591613216)
(16.49283981702582, 92.08888919009816, 208.0048069988394)`

Comment: In ATOM the entire error messages are: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macuser/darkflow-master/video_processing.py", line 2, in <module>
    from darkflow.net.build import TFNet
  File "/Users/macuser/darkflow-master/darkflow/net/build.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .framework import create_framework
  File "/Users/macuser/darkflow-master/darkflow/net/framework.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import yolo`

Comment: `File "/Users/macuser/darkflow-master/darkflow/net/yolo/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import predict
  File "/Users/macuser/darkflow-master/darkflow/net/yolo/predict.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ...cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes import yolo_box_constructor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darkflow.cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes'`

Comment: This proves to me that the issue lies with ATOM not being able to run in a virtual environment